# How to get property name and class name in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How to get name of the property or class name in TypeScript.
Just like `nameof()` function in C# language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically class name is under property `name` of its object if you are referencing constructor. If object is an instance of some class, you need to get its constructor and then get a name. Say we have class Test:

```
class Test {
   someProp = null;
   someFunc() {}
}
```

You can get its name just by referencing `name` property:

```
Test.name
```

if we have eg. variable testInstance which is instance of Test class we need to get to its constructor by `constructor` property and then get a name:

```
instance.constructor.name
```

As functions are also constructors, you can do the same with them:

```
instance.someFunc.name
```

Unfortunately we can't get property name (even by iterating through instance's keys some variables can store the same value or reference to same object though).

However there are probably plenty ways to achieve your goal. Eg. if you want to set as params all of properties stored in instance you can iterate through every property by `for in` loop. Another way is to store not only a value but whole object as `key-value` pair in variable